# Population change over time

Tags: java

I'm having some problems with my program, i ask the user to enter the start population,daily growth in percent, and how many days they will multiply. Then calculate the end population for each day, while making sure they are constraints to the user entered data. I keep getting back the same results for each day and the constraints aren't doing their job either.

```
input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the starting number of organisms");
startPopulation=Double.parseDouble(input);
input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter their daily population increase as a percentage");
increase=Float.parseFloat(input);
input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter how many days they will multiply in");
daysofIncrease=Double.parseDouble(input);
for (int days=0;days<=daysofIncrease+1;days++)
{

  if (startPopulation>=2 || increase >0 || daysofIncrease>=1)
  {
         endPopulation=(startPopulation*increase)+startPopulation;
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is the organisms end population: "+endPopulation+" for day: "+days);
  }

      else
        { 
          input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the starting number of organisms");
          startPopulation=Double.parseDouble(input);
          input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter their daily population increase as a percentage");
          increase=Float.parseFloat(input);
          input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter how many days they will multiply in");
          daysofIncrease=Double.parseDouble(input);

      }
      }
      }
    }
```

Comment: "Please enter the starting number of **orgranisms**" I glanced at it and read it slightly wrong

Comment: @Troubleshoot That comment isn't in the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thought it said *Please enter the starting number of organisms* though. He spelt it wrong you see.

Comment: sorry about that i should have looked it over more before i posted

Comment: @Troubleshoot I believe hexafraction's point is that the comment section isn't here to share innuendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
endPopulation=(startPopulation*increase)+startPopulation;
```

Will not calculate the end population correctly. You haven't used daysofIncrease at all.

I think you'll need to loop through the days. Note that I have not tested this, may need tweaking, but it should give you the idea:

```
double interimPopulation = startPopulation;
for (int days=1; days<=daysofIncrease; days++) {
   interimPopulation *= (1.0 + (increase/100.0));  //get next day's population 
}
endPopulation = interimPopulation;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set somewhere in your loop this:
`startPopulation = endPopulation;`
And then you make another iteration of the loop.
Try this for example

`endPopulation=(startPopulation*increase)+startPopulation;`

`startPopulation = endPopulation;`

And if you don't want to lose the initial value of startPopulation,
just store it somewhere, before you change it (the way I suggest).